# How to save all changes on DB if DataTable.GetChanges() don't have last changes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

I work with windows forms and on the form I have a DataGridView. This gridView I fill with a DataTable dt. The dt I fill with OdbcDataAdapter. For save the changes I use adaper.Update(dt) on Event Handler gridView_RowLeave. The problem is that dt doesn't have last changes of gridView. For exemple if I modify some data in one row or add a new row with data when I leave that row the method dt.GetChages() return false and I must leave more that 1 row for dt.GetChanges() return true. Where can be the problem? Here is my code:

```
Private Sub FillGridview()
  Dim adapter As OdbcDataAdapter

  Dim sCommand As New OdbcCommand("Select * from SPEAKERS", con)
  adapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sCommand)
  adapter.UpdateCommand = UpdateCommand() 'return a query for Update 
  adapter.InsertCommand = InsertCommand() 'return a query for Insert but without ID
  adapter.DeleteCommand = DeleteCommand()

  Try
    adapter.Fill(dt)
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try
  gridView.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub gridView_RowLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles gridView.RowLeave
gridView.EndEdit()
If dt.GetChanges() IsNot Nothing Then
  Try
    Dim res As Integer = adapter.Update(dt)
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    dt.Clear()
    adapter.Fill(dt)
  End Try
  If Not dt.HasErrors Then
    dt.AcceptChanges()
  End If
  gridView.Refresh()
End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea why dt don't have last changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it think its because data tables don't maintain connection to a source...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a bindingSource component to handle data and do not link the grid directly to data

Comment: you have in mind this: 
If CType(GridEx1.DataSource, DataTable).GetChanges() IsNot Nothing Then... Some problem :(